# _layout file in cshtml project is not reflected in file that inherit from it unless in the same directory

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, razor

I have Asp.net (cshtml) application that has a couple of modules each stored in different directory. I have a shared directory which contains both the _layout and CSS file. When I reference this layout file in other files that inherit from it, the CSS and layout etc from the layout does not reflect, although the C# functionality is executed.

However, if I place a copy of the _layout file in each of the inheriting directories and reference this file in the inheriting files instead, the layout, look and feel is inherited.

What could be causing this?

Comment: _Sounds_ like an issue with paths - post the `_layout.cshtml` - just the section you expect to be working.

Comment: @EdSF what do you mean by your comment? The paths are correct as far as I can tell; if it was not the ide would complain about the paths etc.

Comment: In your question above, you (seem) to scope issues to CSS (can't tell, that's why you have to provide more info) - the first place to look is how those CSS files are referenced (paths) in the pages (that may go x levels down) that use said `_layout`. Good luck..

Comment: @EdSF thanks for the suggestions.however, all those have been considered. i thought there maybe some reasons maybe the files are not loaded? is this possible? could anything from the iis or iis express be blocking the loading of the files correctly? probably some configuration that i may need to consider?

Comment: @EdSF see my answer below. figured it out eventually.

Comment: Yup, it turned out to be paths :) Good to see you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized from using the developer tools that the reason the css was not loaded was because the path the application was looking for it is the same one it is in. eg. if page is in /folder1/subfolder1, it would be looking for the path "testhost:9090/appl/folder1/subfolder1", although the CSS file is actually in the folder "testhost:9090/appl/shared".

What I was using to reference initially was for instance if i'm in the subfolder1 mentioned above, to get to the shared folder, I would reference it as 
**link href="../appl/shared/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /.** This did not complain on the editor, but was not loaded in the browser.

Therfore, I have switched to referencing everything from the root directory as
 **link href="~/appl/shared/assets/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /**

Please note the **~** to go to the root directory. Hope this saves someone some time.